# How can I count the number of characters in a UTF-8 string in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a string that contains both English and Russian characters. How can I count the number of characters in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use utf8;
my $str='test ТЕСТ';
print length($str);
```

If you read string from file, you should read it as utf-8

```
open my $fh,'<:utf8','filename.ext';
```

Comment: `my $str='Çirçös';
print length($str);` without utf-8 also it will display some numbers

Comment: @run, Not necessarily the right ones, though. If the source is UTF-8, one needs to use `use utf8;`. If the source isn't UTF-8, then `$str` is just a string of bytes and `length` will return the number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Encode :

```
meAkemi:~$ perl -e 'use Encode; $_="é"; print length( Encode::decode_utf8($_)),"\n"'
1
```